# Passing an array from servlet to jsp along with a bean

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist, package

I'm passing an array of beans from servlet to jsp. I also want to send status "onHand" for each bean. I'm using arrayList for the status.

In Servlet:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import pckg.ProductBean;



public class GetProducts extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException  {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Vector<String[]> v = DBHelper.runQuery("SELECT * FROM SKU;");
    ProductBean [] beans = new ProductBean[v.size()];
    ArrayList<String> onHand=new ArrayList<String>();
    //onHand.add("a");
    for(int i=0; i < v.size(); i++)  {
        String [] tmp = v.elementAt(i);

        Vector<String[]> on = DBHelper.runQuery("SELECT on_hand_quantity FROM on_hand where sku='"+tmp[0]+"' ;");
        if((on.size())>0){
        String [] tmp1 = on.elementAt(0);
        if(Integer.parseInt(tmp1[0])>0){
            onHand.add("InStock");}
            else if(Integer.parseInt(tmp1[0])==0){
            onHand.add("MoreOnTheWay");
            }

        }
        beans[i] = new ProductBean(tmp[0],tmp[1],tmp[2],tmp[3],tmp[4],
            tmp[5],tmp[8],Double.parseDouble(tmp[6]),Double.parseDouble(tmp[7]));

        }
        request.setAttribute("p_beans",beans);
    request.setAttribute("onHand",onHand);





    String toDo = "/WEB-INF/jsp/cameraList.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(toDo); 
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);                              

    }
}
```

In JSP page:

```
    <%@ page import = "java.util.*"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
    charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/cameraList.css" type="text/css"></link>

   <script src="../script/jquery.js"></script>    
    <script src="../script/cameraList.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="main"> 
     <% ArrayList<String> onHand=(ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("onHand");%>

    <c:forEach items="${p_beans}" var="item">


    <table >        
        <tr><td rowspan=5><img id="image" src="upload_dir/${item.image}" style="height:350px; width:350px; background-color:yellow";></td>

        <td><b> ${item.vendor}  ${item.model}  ${item.category}</b></td></tr>

        <tr><td width=45%> Price:$${item.retail}</td><td>Status:</td></tr>

        <c:url value="/servlet/GetProductDetails?" var="myURL">
                <c:param name="sku" value="${item.sku}" />
                </c:url>
        <tr><td><a href="${myURL}" >Get Details</a></td>
        <c:url value="/servlet/OrderPage" var="cartURL">
                <c:param name="itemID" value="${item.sku}" />
                </c:url>
        <td><a href="${cartURL}">Add To Cart</a></td></tr>




    </table>    
    </c:forEach>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error in server:
An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/cameraList.jsp at line 44:

```
41: <body>
42: 
43:     <div id="main"> 
44:     <% ArrayList<String> onHand=(ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("onHand");%>
45:     <c:forEach items="${p_beans}" var="item">
46:     
47:     <table >
```

Comment: suppose you are passing a String attribute in the controller and expecting a `(ArrayList<String>` in the JSP.

Comment: Try to do like this. `<% ArrayList<String> onHand=(ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("onHand");%> `

Comment: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/cameraList.jsp at line 44:                   

41: <body>
42: 
43:  <div id="main"> 
44:  <% ArrayList<String> onHand=(ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("onHand");%>
45:  
46:  <c:forEach items="${p_beans}" var="item">
47:)

Answer (score 1):

**request.getParameter()** always return a String and it is basically use to get data from a form submitted by the user or to get the data from query string. 
Because you are calling **getParameter()** , it will return String and therefore you are getting that exception.

As per your question, because you are setting value for **onHand** field as attribute in request, you should call **getAttribute()** method in JSP. Return type for **getAttribute()** is Object.

Comment: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/cameraList.jsp at line 44

41: <body>
42: 
43:  <div id="main"> 
44:  <% ArrayList<String> onHand=(ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("onHand");%>
45:  
46:  <c:forEach items="${p_beans}" var="item">
47:

Comment: Please share your servlet code, where you are declaring onHand variable.

Comment: ArrayList<String> onHand=new ArrayList<String>();
onHand.add("a");                                                                                                  request.setAttribute("p_beans",beans);
 request.setAttribute("onHand",onHand);

Comment: Have you imported ArrayList in your JSP? that could be the only reason for this error.

Comment: Yes.<%@ page import = "java.util.*"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

Comment: Or Is there any other way where I can send a bean and a set of  values(whose size is same as the size of the bean) from servlet to jsp?

Comment: Can you provide your servlet and jsp code, so that I can have a look in my environment, as all answers to this question is working fine for me in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%
 String param = request.getAttribute("onHand");
%>

<c:forEach items="${p_beans}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td>iterated fields</td>
        <td>
        ..
        ..
        <td><%=param%></td>


    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot cast from String to ArrayList

It seems like your `onHand` object is of `String` type which you are setting your servlet/controller class (using `request.setAttribute("onHand",onHand)`), so you need to typecast to `String` rather than `ArrayList<String>` as shown below in your JSP:

```
<% String onHand= (String)request.getAttribute("onHand"); %>
```

Also, the important point is that you need to use **[request.getAttribute(key)](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) to retrieve the objects** inside JSP.

Comment: suppose `request.getAttribute()`

Comment: thanks, corrected the typo i.e., changed `getAttriute` to `getAttribute`

Comment: This is my arraylist:                                                            
 ArrayList<String> onHand=new ArrayList<String>();
 onHand.add("a");                                                                                    JSP error: <% ArrayList<String> onHand=(ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("onHand");%>